# The "devenv.exe" runs very slow in VS2013 command prompt, why?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I start a VS2013 update 5 command prompt. And run `devenv /?`. It stops like this:

[image]

After a long time, it gives the output. And this happens when compilation at command line.

I never encountered such issue before. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Have you changed something? Installed another Visual Studio version perhaps? VS 2017 RC can cause issues sometimes. This isn't something common, so it isn't possible to say "Do this to fix it". Have you tried using procmon to see what's going on?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't install VS 2017 RC. I will try procmon. This indeed a rare issue. I posted this to try my luck... If I found anything, I will share it.